# Python Pyramid - Add multiple chameleon base templates

Tags: python, pyramid, chameleon, template-tal, template-metal

I am using [this](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_cookbook/dev/templates.html#using-a-beforerender-event-to-expose-chameleon-base-template) procedure to use a base template which the other templates can derive from.

How can I create multiple base templates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just register them both:

```
from pyramid.renderers import get_renderer

def add_base_template(event):
    base = get_renderer('templates/base.pt').implementation()
    base2 = get_renderer('templates/base2.pt').implementation()
    event.update({'base': base, 'base2': base2})
```

And then choose which to use in your template for each page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:tal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/tal"
      xmlns:metal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/metal"
      metal:use-macro="base">
    <tal:block metal:fill-slot="content">
        My awesome content.
    </tal:block>
</html>
```

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:tal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/tal"
      xmlns:metal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/metal"
      metal:use-macro="base2">
    <tal:block metal:fill-slot="content">
        Content on a totally different page.
    </tal:block>
```

I believe a template doesn't have to be the whole HTML element, so you could instead expand 2 macros into the same final template

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:tal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/tal"
      xmlns:metal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/metal">
    <body>
        <div metal:use-macro="section1">
            <tal:block metal:fill-slot="content">
                Content for template "section1".
            </tal:block>
        </div>
        <div metal:use-macro="section2">
            <tal:block metal:fill-slot="content">
                Content for template "section2".
            </tal:block>
        </div>
    </body>
```